# ENUM usage in conditional expressions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

I have a simple java if condition with a boolean comparison and a Enum comparison.

```
if(testBoolean && testEnumObj != TestEnum.Test) {
   //TO DO:
}
```

I got a suggestion from my supervisor to split this into two if blocks for performance reasons. I wanted to confirm whether the above expression will have an impact in the performance or memory occupancy instead of having two if block as below.

```
if(testBoolean) {
   if(testEnumObj != TestEnum.Test) {
     // TO DO:
   }
}
```

I am not seeing any performance improvement in splitting the first expression into second. Just wanted to confirm to support my argument with my reviewer.

Comment: I have to disagree with your supervisor here. they are both the same.

Comment: No differences. Ask the supervisor what _exact_ performance gain you get with this.

Comment: Since you are using `&&`, the performance is the same. If you were just using `&` then it would have made a difference.

Comment: Java's conditional operators are short-circuiting; there will be no performance benefit or impact from using one over the other.

Comment: Thanks you all for your confirmation.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the reviewer's concern should be readability rather than performance.  In general changing code at this level for performance reasons is a bad idea; whereas conforming to applicable standards for readability is a valid reason to favor one of these forms over the other.

That said, for my money it seems like

```
if(testBoolean && (testEnumObj != TestEnum.Test)) {
 //TO DO:
}
```

is closer to correct than either of the above ways, because

(1) your way makes someone stop and think about the order of operations

(2) the "corrected" way wastes an indentation level

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation..Sorry I dont have reputation to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no improvement because `&&` is a short-circuiting operator that won't evaluate second condition if the first one is `false`. This is explained in [JLS §15.23. Conditional-And Operator &&](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is false, the value of the conditional-and expression is false and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.

There would be a difference if you were using `&` e.g. `testBoolean & testEnumObj != TestEnum.Test` which would evaluate both conditions but it would be more readable to switch it to `&&` instead of using a nested `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation..Sorry I dont have reputation to accept the answer.

Comment: @Angu2787 You don't have to have any reputation to accept an answer to your own question. Just hit the green check mark that appears next to the question

Comment: you can also make a point that nesting code with superficial `if` should be avoided as it's making code less readable.

Comment: Sonar might actually complain if you split your "if" up like that.

Answer (score 1):

Below is basic class that have same condition as ur code given

```
class sovjava{

    public  static void main(String ...a){
        boolean i=true;
        boolean j=true;

        if(i && j){

        }
        if(i){
            if(j){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

//This is the byte code seen by `javap -c sovjava` from 5 to 17 observe that both gonna convert into same

```
Compiled from "sovjava.java"
class sovjava {
  sovjava();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_1
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_1
       5: ifeq          12
       8: iload_2
       9: ifeq          12
      12: iload_1
      13: ifeq          20
      16: iload_2
      17: ifeq          20
      20: return
}
```

Both are same in terms of comparing the condition